# Using jQuery tablesorter, I can't get it to do work for my table. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hey guys so I am trying to use the jQuery plugin table sorter (tablesorter.com). I made a test page based off their demo and it worked no problem. However now I am trying to implement it into my website and I can't get it to do anything for me. here is my code.

HTML/PHP

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="orgTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_name");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_description");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_system_name");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_status");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_client");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_actions");?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?foreach ($organizations as $organizationObj) {
    foreach ($organizationObj as $curOrg) {
        if($curOrg->get("name") == "System"){
            //Hide the System organization from vCloud 
            continue;
        }?> 
    <tbody> 
    <tr>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("name");?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("description")===""?"None":$curOrg->get("description")?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("systemName")?></td>
        <td><?=$status[$curOrg->get('status')];?></td>
        <td id="client<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>">            
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")==0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-tiny btn-reverse associate" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>"><?=$languageDB->berkGet("action_associate");?></button>
            <?} else{ 
                $client=new client($curOrg->get("clientId"));?>
                <?=$client->get("companyName");?>
            <?}?>
        </td>
        <td><a href="/organizationDetails.php?id=<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" class="btn btn-tiny"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")>0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-tiny" id="remove" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" data-name="<?=$curOrg->get('name');?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>
            <?}?>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

    <?}
}?>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#orgTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any error you get?

Comment: I am not receiving any errors on the http side of things or the javascript side of thing.

Comment: `<script>` tags should not be self closing.

Comment: thanks for the tip, never knew this I have never used javascript much. I have fixed the tags but it is still not working.

Comment: My issue has been solved. The <tbody> tags needed to be put outside of the for loops. Thank you everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `<tbody>` outside the for loops.

```
...
</thead>

<tbody> 
<?foreach ($organizations as $organizationObj) {
    foreach ($organizationObj as $curOrg) {
        if($curOrg->get("name") == "System"){
            //Hide the System organization from vCloud 
            continue;
        }?> 

    <tr>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("name");?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("description")===""?"None":$curOrg->get("description")?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("systemName")?></td>
        <td><?=$status[$curOrg->get('status')];?></td>
        <td id="client<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>">            
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")==0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-tiny btn-reverse associate" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>"><?=$languageDB->berkGet("action_associate");?></button>
            <?} else{ 
                $client=new client($curOrg->get("clientId"));?>
                <?=$client->get("companyName");?>
            <?}?>
        </td>
        <td><a href="/organizationDetails.php?id=<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" class="btn btn-tiny"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")>0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-tiny" id="remove" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" data-name="<?=$curOrg->get('name');?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>
            <?}?>
    </tr>    
    <?}
}?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the script tag cannot be a self closing tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#orgTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
```

Comment: Note the first line the script tag that you are using is self closing which is incorrect and later script tags won't load due to this

Comment: I have added the tags and still no change.

Comment: is it throwing any errors in firebug or the console you are using?

Comment: Try the above answer now!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery datatables

in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#orgTable").DataTable(); 
    } 
);
```

https://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

**UPDATE**:
If you dont want to change ur tablesorter or use any other jQuery plugin for table sorting,check ur `<script>` tags

use :

`<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

instead of :

`<script type="text/javascript"/>`

Comment: I have updated the tags and it is still not working.

Comment: Well check with inspect element in 'network' or resources session must be throwing any errors, wich in this case i believe your script path must be bad.

Comment: Well it seems like the jQuery problem, check ur jQuery version or redownload the latest jQuery lib.

Comment: I have fixed my issue. The <tbody> tag needed to be outside the for loop and the script tags needed to be closed. Thank you for your help though :)

Comment: Im glad you fixed it.