# Jquery tablesorter plugin trying to disable headers from sorting but it is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tablesorter

So I have a table that I am sorting using the jQuery plugin tablersorter (tablesorter.com). there are two headers in my table that I do not want to be able to sort by and am trying to disable. I used the example provided on the website but it just seems to break the sorting and not let me sort at all. This is my current code.

HTML

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="orgTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_name");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_description");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_system_name");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_status");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_client");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_actions");?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?foreach ($organizations as $organizationObj) {
    foreach ($organizationObj as $curOrg) {
        if($curOrg->get("name") == "System"){
            //Hide the System organization from vCloud 
            continue;
        }?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("name");?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("description")===""?"None":$curOrg->get("description")?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("systemName")?></td>
        <td><?=$status[$curOrg->get('status')];?></td>
        <td id="client<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>">            
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")==0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-tiny btn-reverse associate" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>"><?=$languageDB->berkGet("action_associate");?></button>
            <?} else{ 
                $client=new client($curOrg->get("clientId"));?>
                <?=$client->get("companyName");?>
            <?}?>
        </td>
        <td><a href="/organizationDetails.php?id=<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" class="btn btn-tiny"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")>0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-tiny" id="remove" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" data-name="<?=$curOrg->get('name');?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>
            <?}?>
    </tr>   
    <?}
}?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("orgTable").tablesorter({ 
        headers: { 
            4: { 
                sorter: false 
            }, 
            5: {               
                sorter: false 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: is there any example for tablersorter which allow you to make 2 headers?

Comment: when you run the tablersorter function by default is will make all headers sortable. I am looking make 2 of my headers no longer be sortable while maintaining the other ones as sortable.

Comment: Anything in the javascript console?

Comment: tablesorter js syntax looks correct, not sure you have correct version included, and not sure tablesorter-widgets library needed.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js" /></script> is what I have included.  Not quite sure what you mean by the widget library. I am a bit new to using javascript/jquery

Comment: ok so I got it to disable 1 column with                             $("#orgTable").tablesorter({ headers: { 4:{sorter:false} } } );    but I can't get it to work for multiple columns

Comment: got it working.  this was my solution.                        $("#orgTable").tablesorter({ headers: { 4:{sorter:false}, 5:{sorter:false} } } ); I don't really see how it differs from my original code but I have it on a single line and it works now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery tablesorter, I can't get it to do work for my table. Where am I going wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189885/using-jquery-tablesorter-i-cant-get-it-to-do-work-for-my-table-where-am-i-goi)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solve but try do add the missing tag .

```
<td><a href="/organizationDetails.php?id=<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" class="btn btn-tiny"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")>0){ ?>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-tiny" id="remove" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" data-name="<?=$curOrg->get('name');?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>
        <?}?> // dont forget to close </td>
```

Also don't use `<?foreach...`
But instead use `<?php foreach...?`

Comment: thanks I didn't notice it missing. It did not resolve the issue however.

Comment: also thanks for the tip on the php tag. the code base I am working in is a bit old which is why you are seeing the php tags the way they are. I am slowly updating it though.