# Jquery Tablesorter pager plugin is not working and breaking my sorting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, tablesorter

I am attempting to make use of the pager plugin for tablesorter (tablesorter.com) and have followed a couple examples I found online but I can't seem to get it to work. When I implement the paging is not working and also it breaks the sorting on the table and it will return an error of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined"

Here is my current code

HTML/PHP

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="orgTable" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_name");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_description");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_system_name");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_status");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_client");?></th>
    <th><?=$languageDB->berkGet("object_organization_actions");?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?foreach ($organizations as $organizationObj) {
    foreach ($organizationObj as $curOrg) {
        if($curOrg->get("name") == "System"){
            //Hide the System organization from vCloud 
            continue;
        }?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("name");?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("description")===""?"None":$curOrg->get("description")?></td>
        <td><?=$curOrg->get("systemName")?></td>
        <td><?=$status[$curOrg->get('status')];?></td>
        <td id="client<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>">            
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")==0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-tiny btn-reverse associate" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>"><?=$languageDB->berkGet("action_associate");?></button>
            <?} else{ 
                $client=new client($curOrg->get("clientId"));?>
                <?=$client->get("companyName");?>
            <?}?>
        </td>
        <td><a href="/organizationDetails.php?id=<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" class="btn btn-tiny"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
            <?if($curOrg->get("clientId")>0){ ?>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-tiny" id="remove" data-uid="<?=$curOrg->get('id');?>" data-name="<?=$curOrg->get('name');?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> </button>
            <?}?></td>
    </tr>   
    <?}
}?>
</tbody>
</table>


<div id="pager" class="pager">
    <form>
        <img src="images/paging-first.png" class="first"/>
        <img src="images/paging-prev.png" class="prev"/>
        <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
        <img src="images/paging-next.png" class="next"/>
        <img src="images/paging-last.png" class="last"/>
        <select class="pagesize">
            <option selected="selected"  value="10">10</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option  value="40">40</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#orgTable").tablesorter(); 
        $("#orgTable").tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")});
    } 
);
```

thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery tablesorter, I can't get it to do work for my table. Where am I going wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189885/using-jquery-tablesorter-i-cant-get-it-to-do-work-for-my-table-where-am-i-goi)

Answer (score 1):

The pager from tablesorter.com requires a version of jQuery older than v1.9 because it uses [`$.browser()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

So you have two choices:

1. Use an older version of jQuery.
2. Try switching to use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) in which you can use either the [pager plugin](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html) or the [pager widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-pager.html) (preferred) for paging.

*Note*: The forked pager is not compatible with the original tablesorter.